# How to overlap the bottom container widget to the clip path container?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-layout, layout

This is my code,

```
return MaterialApp(

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Example',
      home: Scaffold(

        backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200,

        body: Column(
           
          children: [
            
            ClipPath(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
              child: Container(   
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.green.shade300,
                child:  Row(
              
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              
                  children: const [
              
                    Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined, color: Colors.black87, size: 30,),
                    Text('Example', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black87,)),
              
                  ],
                ),
                ),
            ),

            Container(
              
              height: 360,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.white,

            ),
            
          ],
  
        ),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my clipper class, its just a basic design that we see on every other flutter app,

```
// clipper class 

class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper <Path> {
 
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path(); 
    path.lineTo(0, size.height / 2 );
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2 , size.height, size.width, size.height / 2 );
    path.lineTo( size.width , 0);

    return path ; 

  }

   @override
   bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper <Path> oldClipper ) {
   return true ; 

   }

}
```

[Current Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZzKv.png)

- i really don't know how we can achieve such things
- clip-path does not have any padding and margin by default
- tried stack but no luck ?
- used alignment property no luck
- i read on other thread that clipping should be done separately not on the whole widget what does that mean ?

Comment: can you post a picture for the requirement as well ?

Comment: i can't edit my post, do i need more reputation , between i want the white container (box) to reach the curved path and overlap it that's what i want .

Comment: Try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/proste_bezier_curve